# Time zone confusion (1 hour off)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, time, timezone

```
Time.use_zone('Pacific Time (US & Canada)') do
  p Time.zone.now
end
```

I get the following: `=> Sun, 14 Apr 2013 20:30:53 PDT -07:00`

Yet when I do Rails Time Zone Select.... it says `-8:00` quite clearly. Why is it -7 in one area and -8 in another?

Other times, time zones like `Hawaii` which are `-10:00` don't get offset by an hour.

I assume this has something to do with DST, but I'm more curious whether it means it's working *properly* or *improperly* and there is something else I need to do.

Ultimately I'm using this in a datepicker, and I find it very odd that when I use `Time.zone.parse` (along with my time zone around filter), its offsetting everything by 1 hour.

THanks

**Edit**

Heres a similar problem I also just experienced with another piece of code

```
2.0.0-p0 :006 >
2.0.0-p0 :006 > u.meetups.in_future.first.meetup_time
  Meetup Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `meetups`.* FROM `meetups` WHERE `meetups`.`user_id` = 1 AND (meetup_time >= '2013-04-23 04:46:48') ORDER BY meetup_time ASC LIMIT 1
 => Tue, 23 Apr 2013 05:43:00 UTC 00:00
2.0.0-p0 :007 >
```

Notice the discrepancy in the result compared to the where clause.

**Edit**

It appears to work for CST properly, but PST is off by ~1 hours?? I feel this is all the same problem, I am just missing a piece of the puzzle.

Comment: Simple question: Have you verified that your your machine, and the SQL DB are using the same timezone information? This would really only cause the issue from the DB (possibly)?

Comment: I have made sure my rails app timezone is UTC, and that I also have an around_filter in the ApplicationController that accounts for the users' timezone that's selected in the select dropdown

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with SQLite (assuming your using Rails default dev DB) to know if it uses system timezone or it's own. But MySQL has a timezone configuration that can differ from the machine which (should it be different) would cause times to be offset in strange ways like that. Just curious if you'd checked that.

Answer (score 2):

The output is correct.  Pacific Daylight Time has an offset of -7, while Pacific Standard Time has an offset of -8.  My guess is that "Rails Time Zone Select" (whatever that is) is only is showing you the "standard" offsets, rather than the current ones.  This is common in time zone pickers.

Hawaii does not implement Daylight Savings Time of any kind, so that addresses your second point.

On your third point, I would have to know more about your database platform to answer why the values are converted to UTC.  Given that these are event times, I would say that they *should* be in UTC.  They could also be in the time zone of the location of the "meetup", but only if the offset from UTC was also stored.  But never should they be in the time zone of the server.

On your fourth point, it's difficult to tell what you mean without more details.  Expand if you feel necessary.